# Why can I simply not get pipedinput/outputstreams to work

Tags: java, io

I am trying to work out for myself how PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream work together. So far the result is complete failure.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements Runnable {

  private PipedOutputStream pause_breaker;
  private PipedInputStream pause_breaker_listener;
  private BufferedReader br;
  private PrintWriter pw;

  public void run() {
    try {
      while(true) {
        System.out.println("Now listening...");
        String text = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("...got " + text);
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("run: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  
  public void pause_test() {
    try {
      // testing piped streams as pausing tool
      pause_breaker = new PipedOutputStream();
      pause_breaker_listener = new PipedInputStream();
      pause_breaker_listener.connect(pause_breaker);
      //pause_breaker.connect(pause_breaker_listener);
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pause_breaker_listener));
      pw = new PrintWriter(pause_breaker);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      new Thread(this).start();
      System.out.println("Waiting for new Thread...");
      //Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("Writing to stream...");
      pw.write("Test");
      pw.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("pause_test: " + e.getMessage());
    }    
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t2 = new Test();
    t2.pause_test();
  }

}
```

The output is like this:

```
$ java Test 
Waiting for new Thread...
Writing to stream...
Now listening...
run: Write end dead
```

It seems nothing is coming through. Can anyone point for me why?

/dr_xemacs

Comment: `pw.println("Test")` as readLine needs a line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Since you're using a BufferedReader to get items from the pipe, each item needs to have a trailing newline
2. You need to revise how the threads communicate that it's time to quit.  The reader thread has an infinite loop, while the writer thread terminates immediately after writing a single line, so the reader thread throws `IOException: pipe broken`.